# What's the mechanism of the warps and the banks in CUDA?

Tags: cuda, bank-conflict

I'm a rookie in learning CUDA parallel programming. Now I'm confused in the global memory access of device. It's about the warp model and coalescence.

There are some points:

1. It's said that threads in one block are split into warps. In each warp there are at most 32 threads. That means all these threads of the same warp will execute simultaneously with the same processor. So what's the senses of half-warp?
2. When it comes to the shared memory of one block, it would be split into 16 banks. To avoid bank conflicts, multiple threads can READ one bank at the same time rather than write in the same bank. Is this a correct interpretation?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. The principal usage of "half-warp" was applied to CUDA processors
   prior to the Fermi generation (e.g. the "Tesla" or GT200 generation,
   and the original G80/G92 generation).  [These GPUs were architected
   with a SM (streaming multiprocessor -- a HW block inside the GPU)
   that had fewer than 32 thread
   processors](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#architecture-1-x).
   The definition of warp was still the same, but the actual HW
   execution took place in "half-warps" at a time.  Actually the
   granular details are more complicated than this, but suffice it to
   say that the execution model caused memory requests to be issued
   according to the needs of a half-warp, i.e. 16 threads within the warp. 
   A full warp that hit a memory transaction would thus generate a
   total of 2 requests for that transaction.

   [Fermi and newer GPUs have at least 32 thread processors per
   SM](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#compute-capability-2-x).
   Therefore a memory transaction is immediately visible across a full
   warp.  As a result,  memory requests are issued at the per-warp
   level, rather than per-half-warp.  However, a full memory request
   can only retrieve 128 bytes at a time. Therefore, for data sizes
   larger than 32 bits per thread per transaction, the memory
   controller may still break the request down into a half-warp size.

   My view is that, especially for a beginner, it's not necessary to
   have a detailed understanding of half-warp.  It's generally
   sufficient to understand that it refers to a group of 16 threads
   executing together and it has implications for memory requests.
2. Shared memory for example on the [Fermi-class
   GPUs](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#shared-memory-2-x)
   is broken into 32 banks.  On [previous
   GPUs](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#shared-memory-1-x)
   it was broken into 16 banks.  Bank conflicts occur any time an
   individual bank is accessed by more than one thread in the same
   memory request (i.e. originating from the same code instruction). 
   To avoid bank conflicts, basic strategies are very similar to the
   strategies for coalescing memory requests, eg. for global memory.  On Fermi and newer GPUs, multiple threads can read the same *address* without causing a bank conflict, but in general the *definition* of a bank conflict is when multiple threads read from the same bank.  For further understanding of shared memory and how to avoid bank conflicts, I would recommend the [NVIDIA webinar](https://developer.nvidia.com/gpu-computing-webinars) on [this topic](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/CUDA/training/sharedmemoryusage_july2011.mp4).